# How do I properly sort in this struct array?

Tags: c++, struct

No matter how I try to swap the structs or the "player data" it won't seem to sort at the end of the program.

The assignment requires to call almost all the functions within the print function.

Any late night people that could help before its due would be == heros.
thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



const int MAX_QBS = 100;

struct qbType{
    string firstname,lastname;
    int attempts,completions,yardsPassing,touchdowns,interceptions;
    double completionPercentage,rating;
};



//Function Prototypes
void read_stats(qbType qbRoster[],int &qbCount);
void print_stats(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount);
void compute_comp_percentage(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount);
void sort_by_name(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount);
void sort_by_rating(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount);
void compute_rating(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount);



//**************MAIN PROGRAM*************************
int main()
{

    int qbCount = 0;
    qbType qbRoster[MAX_QBS];

    sort_by_name(qbRoster,qbCount);

    sort_by_rating(qbRoster,qbCount);


    print_stats(qbRoster,qbCount);
}
//Function Name:        read_stats
//Purpose:              reads file data into array of structs and count number of players
//Incoming:             qbRoster[], &qbCount
//Outgoing:             void
void read_stats(qbType qbRoster[],int &qbCount)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("football-in.txt");
    if(infile.fail())
    {
        cout<< "ERROR opening input file"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while(!infile.eof())
    {   
        getline(infile,qbRoster[qbCount].firstname);
        getline(infile,qbRoster[qbCount].lastname);
        infile >> ws;
        infile >> qbRoster[qbCount].attempts;
        infile >> qbRoster[qbCount].completions;
        infile >> qbRoster[qbCount].yardsPassing;
        infile >> qbRoster[qbCount].touchdowns;
        infile >> qbRoster[qbCount].interceptions;
        infile >>ws;
        qbCount ++;
    }
    infile.close();
}
//Function Name:        print_stats
//Purpose:              prints stats from array of structs into table
//Incoming:             qbRoster[] , int qbcount
//Outgoing:             void
void print_stats(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount)
{
    read_stats(qbRoster,qbCount);
    compute_comp_percentage(qbRoster,qbCount);
    compute_rating(qbRoster,qbCount);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Quarterback";
    cout << setw(17) << right << "Att.";
    cout << setw(17) << "Comp.";
    cout <<setw(17)<<"Pct.";
    cout <<setw(17)<<"Yards";
    cout << setw(17)<<"TD";
    cout <<setw(17)<<"Int.";
    cout <<setw(17)<<"Rating"<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < qbCount;i++)
        {

            cout <<qbRoster[i].firstname << qbRoster[i].lastname;
            cout <<setw(17)<<right<<qbRoster[i].attempts;
            cout <<setw(17)<<qbRoster[i].completions;
            cout <<setw(17)<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<qbRoster[i].completionPercentage;
            cout <<setw(17)<<qbRoster[i].yardsPassing;
            cout <<setw(17)<<qbRoster[i].touchdowns;
            cout <<setw(17)<<qbRoster[i].interceptions;
            cout <<setw(17)<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<qbRoster[i].rating<< endl;


        }
}
//Function Name:        compute_comp_percentage
//Purpose:              computes the completion percentage
//Incoming:             qbRoster[], int qbcount
//Outgoing:             void
void compute_comp_percentage(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount)
{

    for(int i = 0;i<qbCount;i++)
    {
        qbRoster[i].completionPercentage = 1.0*qbRoster[i].completions / qbRoster[i].attempts;
    }

}
//Function Name:        compute_rating
//Purpose:              computes the total rating
//Incoming:             qbRoster[], int qbcount
//Outgoing:             void
void compute_rating(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<qbCount;i++)
    {

        qbRoster[i].rating= ((static_cast<double>(qbRoster[i].completions)*3)+static_cast<double>(qbRoster[i].yardsPassing) + (static_cast<double>(qbRoster[i].touchdowns)*10))/(static_cast<double>(qbRoster[i].attempts) +(8* static_cast<double>(qbRoster[i].interceptions)));

    }
}
//Function Name:        sort_by_name
//Purpose:              sorts by last name in ascending order
//Incoming:             qbRoster[], int qbcount
//Outgoing:             void
void sort_by_name(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount)
{

    struct qbType temp;
    int j=0,i=0,minIndex=0;
    j = i + 1;
    for(int i=0;i< qbCount;i++)
        {

        if(qbRoster[i].lastname > qbRoster[j].lastname)
            {
            temp = qbRoster[i];


            qbRoster[i] = qbRoster[j];


            qbRoster[j] = temp;

            }
}
}

//Function Name:        sort_by_rating
//Purpose:              sorts by last name in descending order
//Incoming:             qbRoster[], int qbcount
//Outgoing:             void

void sort_by_rating(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount)
{
    struct qbType temp;
    int j=0, i=0;
    j = i +1;
    for(int i = 0;i<qbCount;i++)
        if(qbRoster[i].rating < qbRoster[j].rating)
            {
                temp = qbRoster[i];
                qbRoster[i] = qbRoster[j];
                qbRoster[j] = temp;
            }


}
```

No errors just no sorting at the end of output either.

Comment: You expect an array to be sorted in one loop? You are quite optimistic.

Comment: Your sorting methods need to use nested loops (assuming you're using bubble sort).

Comment: `void sort_by_name(qbType qbRoster[],int qbCount) { std::sort(qbRoster, qbRoster + qbCount, [&](qbType& v1, qbType& v2) { return v1.lastname < v2.lastname; }); }`

Comment: 1. You will never receive a result. You are first sorting empty arrays in main, and then calling print_stats. This will read the inout file. After you sorted an empty array. 2. You can use a one-liner for sorting. ````std::sort````. This will also work, but 3. Do not and never use plain arrays in C++. Use std::vector. Add extractor and inserter to your struct. 4. Use C++

Comment: This looks like homework. What are the constraints on use of `std::`?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps (bubblesort):

```
void sort_by_name(qbType qbRoster[], int qbCount)
{
    struct qbType temp;
    (int j = 0; j < qbCount; j++) 
    {
       for (int i = 1; i < (qbCount - j); i++) 
       {
           if(qbRoster[i-1].lastname > qbRoster[i].lastname) 
          {
              temp = qbRoster[i];
              qbRoster[i] = qbRoster[i-1];
              qbRoster[i-1] = temp;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I allways liked this gif: [link to gif](https://imgur.com/gallery/fq0A8hx)